# Log Request execution Time along with requested URL

Tags: asp.net, performance, iis, webforms

I'm running a ASP.NET WEBFORMS application on a windows 2012 Server.

I need to be able to calculate average execution times for each page in my application.

I know the IIS logs have a time-taken column. However I believe this time includes network transit. I need to capture server execution time.

I know there is a performance counter asp.net request execution time, but I don't know of a way to tie that back to the requested URL (or more specifically, the URL Stem). Without that, I'm just getting an average for the entire site.